# Three.js .position.copy()

Tags: javascript, three.js

Please tell me where I can read about `.position.copy()`.

Example

```
 cube.position.copy();
```

The book found

```
cube.position.copy (new THREE.Vector3 (x, y, z));
```

But about that nothing is written in the documents too. It is present in a documentation? I could not find.

As markups then understand that `.copy ()` must be passed Vector3? Instead of the coordinates as

```
cube.position.set (x, y, z);
```

Comment: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D. `Object3D` has a `position` property.

Comment: It's not written about position.x, position.y, position.z. position.set ()? position.copy ()?

Comment: `position` is a `Vector3`. http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Vector3

Comment: Thank you. I just misread the documentation. Now like as understood.

Comment: Link for comment 1 has changed to 
  https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Object3D . . . . .  Link for comment 3 has changed to 
  https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Vector3

Answer (score 4):

I saw this post while looking for the same documentation or how to properly copy a position.  This works and passes 'use strict' ...

```
new_cube.position.copy( old_cube.position );
```

From: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.copy

Answer (score 0):

It actually sets position with a Vector3 object as a param. You can find docs here:

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.copy